# How to lay out events in a calendar day view

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, flexbox, calendar

I'm creating a calendar web application using React (HTML/CSS/JS). I'm trying to figure out how to place events into the calendar in a way that automatically stacks them vertically and horizontally based on their start and end times. Microsoft teams does this in their calendar. I've provided an image here of what the layout should look like.

[image: MS Teams Example]

I've tried using flexbox and tried positioning them absolutely based on calculated overlaps and offsets. No luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm looking for help with the algorithm to do this. Im not looking for specific code.

I have an array of events

```
[
{start: datetime, end: datetime},
{start: datetime, end: datetime},
...
]
```

I've created a function that returns a 2x2 matrix of "colisions" between events. E.x. for the pic posted above:

|  | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| c | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| d | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I feel like from this I should be able to determine the width of each event (100%, 50%, 33.3%, etc). and the offset from the left of the page (i.e. column 1, coulmn 2. etc)

Comment: Please look into CSS Grid. Or you can check some readymade JS libraries for timeline charts. https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Thanks for the input. At first glance, this looks like a simple problem where a grid would help, but its actually more complicated than it looks. Its almost like it needs a mix of flexbox and absolute positioning.

I should mention that this is a dynamic page thats linked to a database so it needs to work for any combination of conflicting events.

Comment: I am afraid you won't get much help unless you post the code that you have tried  or what you have right now.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point! I guess I'm looking for more help with wrapping my head around the algorithm to do this. Going to edit my main post